# Can't create PHPMailer object instance from PHPMailer composer

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer

Hi I am currently working on a project that has a forgot password system in it. I decided to use PHPMailer to send reset password email to the user and I installed it via Composer and it is now in the vendor folder. However, after implementing the sample codes, PHP throws an error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mail in /opt/lampp/htdocs/capstone-admin/process/loginFunctions.php on line 98

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isSMTP() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/capstone-admin/process/loginFunctions.php:98 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/capstone-admin/process/loginFunctions.php on line 98
```

Here is a portion of my code in the loginFunctions.php:

```
<?php 
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require __DIR__. '/../vendor/autoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    // More codes ......
?>
```

And my directory structure is:

[image: Directory structure]

**UPDATE**

1. I tried searching common stack overflow questions regarding the error and even look through youtube videos but so far no luck! Any help would be appreciated been stuck for days
2. Grateful for the help from the comments but no luck so far unfortunately
3. I provided an imgur image showing the debug screenshot right after
   `$mail = new PHPMailer();` occurs:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @MartinZeitler Sorry i don't get what you mean. I just followed the phpmailer sample codes

Comment: @Martin, those `use` statements are correct; they are namespace aliases, not file references.

Comment: The code you have there looks correct - if you cut it back to *only* that code, does it work? I suspect a structural issue in your `loginFunctions.php` file.

Comment: @Synchro I tried putting it in my index.php but still no luck it is still the same error sadly

Comment: @Synchro it is still rather obvious, that `new PHPMailer()` does not construct as expected... setting a break-point into the constructor might explain why it behaves that way. Also, `new PHPMailer(true)` enables exceptions.

Comment: Could you please show composer.json?

Comment: No it’s not “obvious”; that’s an assumption. `var_dump($mail)` after creating the instance, see what you’ve got.

Comment: `{
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.1"
    }
}`

@Dmitry

Comment: Check this page, please - https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: @Synchro it shows NULL if im correct

Comment: Could you please provide more code?

Comment: @MartinZeitler https://imgur.com/a/fYxgOVM here is the link showing the debug after the PHPMailer line occurs apparently it is still uninitialised? It creates a new variable called $mailA form what i observed

Comment: @Dmitry may i know which one exactly so I do not send irrelevant codes sections but I included an imgur link above showing the debug screenshot which I hope could help

Comment: Could you please show this line - loginFunctions.php on line 98

Comment: @Dmitry Oh that one it's in the code block above I basically show the codes that triggers the error it is the `$mail->isSMTP();`

Comment: The variable `$mail` followed by the weird accented `A` symbol looks a bit like the space after the word `$mail` in `$mail = new ...` is a weird special character. Remove that entire line and manually type it anew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it's the correct one `vendor/autoload.php` (see inline comment):

- It reads `new PHPMailer` instead of `new PHPMailer()` - not alike the code snippet above.
- `$mailÂ` also looks strange, while `$mail` is unknown. There might be some invisible control character in between `$mail` and `=`. If it dumps something then likely `var_dump($mailÂ);`

And if it wasn't that, then ...

- Try running [`composer dump-autoload --verbose`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-).

In order to throw / catch exceptions, construct alike this:

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    // relative vs. absolute path sometimes make a difference.
    require __DIR__. '/../vendor/autoload.php';
    // require '../vendor/autoload.php';

    try {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you guys! I finally solved it it is indeed some special invisible character so I have to delete and retype the code!